# Sorting on association with has_many_through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, has-many-through

I Want to get sorted result using price.

> I want to get result with sorting order by price when i do
>   `hotel.packages`

I have two models`(hotel and package )` with `has_many :through` relationship. both are connected to each other with through relationship and its model name is `package_price`

Hotel model is:

```
 class Hotel < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :package_prices, :dependent => :destroy 
    has_many :packages, :through => :package_prices, :order => 'package_prices.price'
  end
```

package model is:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :package_prices, :dependent => :destroy #foreign key package_id
    has_many :hotels, :through => :package_prices, :order => 'package_prices.price'
end
```

package_price model is:

```
class PackagePrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :package
  belongs_to :hotel
end
```

package_prices table fields:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| package_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price      | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| hotel_id   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to get packages of hotel by sorted with price.

Comment: What you have already doesn't work?

Comment: I want to get result with sorting order by price when i do `hotel.packages`

Comment: That is exactly what `has_many :packages ...` on your `Hotel` model is doing, as @Vimsha pointed out.

Comment: Hotel can have many packages and each package has a price

Comment: Can you give an example of how your application isn't working correctly?